# haskell application project documentation

Tags: haskell

> What is literate programming? To quote Dr. Knuth:
>       "The main idea is to regard a program as a communication to human beings rather than as a set of instructions to a computer."

What are the popular ways to generate haskell application project documentation? Please mention main strength area / key benefits of each method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most common way is to use [Haddock markup](http://www.haskell.org/haddock/doc/html/index.html).

To do this you start a comment line with `-- |`. The documentation continues until the next non-comment line:

```
-- |This is a doc comment
--  which continues onto the next line.
```

If you want to generate links to other parts of the documentation, use single quotes around function names. If you want to specify fixed-width font, enclose text within `@` symbols. If you want to specify a code block, start a comment line with `-- >`.

Here's a real-world example taken from the [GHC Base source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-Base.html), which compiles into the documentation seen on [this page](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3amap).

```
-- | 'map' @f xs@ is the list obtained by applying @f@ to each element
-- of @xs@, i.e.,
--
-- > map f [x1, x2, ..., xn] == [f x1, f x2, ..., f xn]
-- > map f [x1, x2, ...] == [f x1, f x2, ...]

map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map _ []     = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

Comment: Just a personal remark here: frequently when I read Haddock annotated code, the code has sometimes more lines of documentation than of code. Personally I feel that a change would do well here e.g. split the code in a documentation section that has only anchors in the code or else. So that the readability of the actual code is retained better.